# How do I report SPAM from WTelegramClient updates?

Tags: telegram-api, wtelegramclient

I am trying to get the text of the message, and if it is large, and exists in the SPAM database, a SPAM report should be sent to the Telegram support service.

```
private Task DisplayMessage(MessageBase messageBase, bool edit = false)
{
  switch (messageBase) {
    case TL.Message m: {
    string text = $"{Peer(m.from_id) ?? m.post_author} in {Peer(m.peer_id)}> {m.message}";
    if (<some checking>)
    _client.Messages_ReportSpam((InputPeer)<???>);
}
}
```

How to get `InputPeer` from `Peer` or from `Message`?